# Tab Ordering for Javascript "Buttons"

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tabindex

I'm trying to create an HTML form (using JSP) which contains Javascript buttons (rather than actual HTML buttons). Everything works great except that I'm unable to tab to the -based Javascript button after the last tabindex.

For example:

```
<li class="lineItem">
<f:label path="ownerPostalCode">Postal Code<em>*</em> </f:label><br />
<f:input path="ownerPostalCode" type="text" id="ownerPostalCode"
   class="required" size="15" maxlength="5" value="" tabindex="16" />
</li>
<li class="lineItem">
  <f:label path="ownerPostalCodeFour">+4</f:label><br />
  <f:input path="ownerPostalCodeFour" type="text" 
   id="ownerPostalCodeFour" size="5" maxlength="5" value="" tabindex="17"/>
</li>
<span class="buttonRow">
  <span class="clearButton" onclick="resetFields
    ('registrationForm', 'ownerInfoSection')">Clear Fields</span>
  <span id="continueButton" class="greenButton" tabindex="18" 
    onclick="stepOneToStepTwo()">Continue</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I understand that tabindex only works with certain input fields (A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA)--as such, the specification of "tabindex='18'" for the #continueButton doesn't work. The desired behavior is that after tabbing to the "ownerPostalCodeFour" field, the user can tab to the #continueButton as one would with a normal button.

Is this at all possible or am I forced to utilize standard HTML buttons to achieve this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using javascript buttons instead of regular ones? There may be a way around this by using elements as they are designed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what browsers you are supporting, but `tabindex="0"` works in latest webkit/Firefox/IE. From an accessibility standpoint, using spans is less than optimal though. Why not at least use an `<a>` tag?

Comment: `<a>` tags are definatly focusable and it makes sense to use an a tag or an input as they just "Scream" click me.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback, Steve. At this point, planning to support the latest Firefox versions (4/5). Didn't think about accessibility and that's a good point I'd neglected. Another thing I forgot to mention is that this is a multipage form (which is actually just one physical HTML form partitioned based on two large <li> sections) which is why I'm not using standard button elements since I wasn't able to achieve the UI effects I was after (though my lack of web dev knowledge may be at fault if that's misguided). I'll give the <a> tags a try and will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: DFU (or, rather, DFP--programmer) oversight on my part. Problem was solved simply by following James' suggestion of using things as they're meant to be used. Apologies for the red herring.